# Getting a Syntax error after running PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql

Can someone please help where is the syntax error in below query when ever I am using the below query I am getting a syntax error?

[query]

```
#su postgres -c 'psql -d ovirt_engine_history -c " UPDATE history_configuration set var_datetime = var_datetime - interval '24 hour' WHERE var_name = 'lastHourAggr' "';
```

[Error after running the above query]

```
hour WHERE var_name = lastHourAggr ": -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
hour WHERE var_name = lastHourAggr ": -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Please help what I am missing in the query

Comment: Get your quotes properly escaped.

Comment: Consider using `psql -u postgres -d ovirt_engine_history -c "…"` without any `su`.

Answer (score 0):

Executed the query without su

```
psql -d ovirt_engine_history -c " UPDATE history_configuration set var_datetime = var_datetime - interval '1 day' WHERE var_name = 'lastDayAggr' "
```